# apache2 external disk permissions

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, file-permissions, symlink

currently I have a hard drive on my pc with all my projects, I want my apache server link all my projects through virtual host but gives me access denied, was that the problem is because it is not the primary disk, I can do about it?

For example:

I use ubuntu 14.04

```
root@MS-7817:/# cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/demo.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName demo.local

    DocumentRoot /home/me/public_html/demo
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/me/public_html/demo/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Site is enabled:

```
me@MS-7817:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 dic 30 17:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 dic 28 03:13 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   35 dic 27 20:02 000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 dic 30 17:01 demo.conf -> ../sites-available/demo.conf
```

Execute:

```
$ ln -s /media/myuser/projectdisk/demo/www/ /home/myuser/public_html/demo
```

Apply to hosts:

```
root@MS-7817:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   MS-7817

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1   demo.local
```

Files exists:

```
root@MS-7817:/# cd /home/me/public_html/demo
root@MS-7817:/home/me/public_html/demo# ll
total 100
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 dic 30 16:30 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 me       me        4096 dic 29 13:49 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me       me        12921 dic 30 16:30 index.php
```

I use the correct permissions:

```
me@MS-7817:/$ id
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) grupos=1000(me),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),33(www-data),46(plugdev),108(lpadmin),124(sambashare)
```

Restart apache correctely:

```
me@MS-7817:/$ sudo service apache2 restart
[sudo] password for me: 
 * Restarting web server apache2
 *
```

But not access to http://demo.local/

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at demo.local Port 80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They were problems of file permissions, default ubuntu mounted disks with read-only permissions for the current user www-data without being read permissions:

```
me@machine:~$ sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/me
ls: no se puede abrir el directorio /media/me: Permiso denegado
```

The solution found here: https://superuser.com/questions/174776/modify-fstab-entry-so-all-users-can-read-and-write-to-an-ext4-volume , i gave him permission to drive and ready :)

```
me@machine:~$ sudo chmod 777 /media/me -R
me@machine:~$ sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/me
total 12
drwxrwxrwx+  3 root root 4096 ene 14 15:33 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 dic 25 13:41 ..
drwxrwxrwx  22 me   me   4096 ene  2 00:36 2TB
```

Comment: This is helpful - but to clarify, did you simply change the fstab to grant permissions, or did you also run the 777 chmod command above?  Or both?  Or just one?  @e-info128

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem
I wanted apache to access files on my external hdd,
but I got the error 403 permission denied.

I solved this by changing the following two lines in /etc/apache2/envvars
(sudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars)

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

I replaced 'www-data' by 'my user name' as follows:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=my user name
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=my user name
```

After this, apache had access to the files